# Переменная PHP в MySQL запросе превращается в 0

Tags: php, html, mysql

Есть переменная $ch_id, которая берется из массива и по началу берется правильно. 
HTML форма:

```
<form method="POST" action="db_change.php">    
        <p><input placeholder="Имя" type="text" name="ch_name" autocomplete="on" /><br />

            <p><input placeholder="Почта" type="email" name="ch_email" autocomplete="on" /><br />

            <p><input placeholder="Телефон" type="tel" name="ch_phone" autocomplete="on" /><br />

            <p><input placeholder="Отдел" type="text" name="ch_division" autocomplete="on" /><br />

            <p><tr><input type="submit" name="update" value="Изменить"/>
            <tr><a href="index.php" class="tab">
                    <input type="button" name="return" value="назад" /></a>        
        </form>
```

PHP код:

```
$sr_id=$_POST['arr'];
        $ch_id =intval($sr_id[0]);
        var_dump($ch_id);
        $ch_name=htmlspecialchars($_POST['ch_name']);
        $ch_email=htmlspecialchars($_POST['ch_email']);
        $ch_phone=htmlspecialchars($_POST['ch_phone']);
        $ch_division=htmlspecialchars($_POST['ch_division']);
        $guery_change="UPDATE `users` SET `name_user`='$ch_name', `email`='$ch_email', `phone_number`='$ch_phone', `division`='$ch_division' WHERE `id_user` = '$ch_id' ";
        var_dump($guery_change);
        $result_change=mysqli_query($link, $guery_change) or die(mysql_error());
        var_dump($result_change);
        if($result_change == 'true') {
            echo "<p> Ваши данные успешно обновлены ";}
                else {
                     echo "<p> Ваши данные не обновлены";}
```

Пока я не нажимаю сабмит:

```
C:\server\data\htdocs\workcourse\db_change.php:27:int 7
C:\server\data\htdocs\workcourse\db_change.php:33:string 'UPDATE `users` SET `name_user`='', `email`='', `phone_number`='', `division`='' WHERE `id_user` = '7' ' (length=102)
```

После нажатия сабмита получаем:

```
C:\server\data\htdocs\workcourse\db_change.php:27:int 0
C:\server\data\htdocs\workcourse\db_change.php:33:string 'UPDATE `users` SET `name_user`='Городкова Анна', `email`='gorodkova@example.com', `phone_number`='453456', `division`='Офис' WHERE `id_user` = '0' ' (length=164)
C:\server\data\htdocs\workcourse\db_change.php:35:boolean true
```

Получается что переменная приходит в запрос не правильно, но я не знаю как это исправить.

Comment: Что за $_POST['arr']? Каким образом этот массив заполняется?

Comment: Все правильно, указал @DaemonHK у вас в посте нет данных `arr` передавайте их повторно в форме, путем `<input  type="hidden" name="arr" value="<?=$_POST['arr']?>" />` указанный код, является примером. Нужно больше информации.

Comment: и вместо шаманских вещей используйте подготовленные выражения http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php ....

Comment: $_POST['arr'] предыдущего скрипта, передается POSTом      <input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$row[0]\" name=\"arr[]\" />

Comment: Создатели mysqli совершили чудовищную ошибку, сделав функцию mysqli_query = ( подготовка+выполнение, только так надо делать. Вообще на первое время забудьте о том что можно клеить запросы самому.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, было решено с помощью сессий и разделения на 2 скрипта. В первом скрипте осталась html форма и такой код

```
    <?php
        session_start(); // Открываем сессию
        $sr_id=$_POST['arr']; // промежуточное присвоение
        $_SESSION['ch_id']=intval($sr_id[0]); // Берем первый элемент массива, делаем из него int и записываем в сессию    
?>
```

Во втором скрипте открываю сессию и ввожу переменную, чтобы было удобно вставлять ее в запрос. Потом собственно сам запрос и вуаля!

```
session_start();
$up_id=$_SESSION['ch_id'];
```

Спасибо всем за комментарии)